# Looking for a fast and reliable way to copy files to SFTP

Tags: networking, ssh, file-transfer, sftp

I always used SFTP for copying up CMS systems, modify system/user files, or files related to sites and similar. Small things. Even if the file was larger, I could just wait it out.

But now I have to transfer large amount of files.
Using WinSCP, I have two problems:

- Due to **latency**, it's really slow to start a transfer. Like that takes 2-3 seconds, and that is a huge minus. **More threads (even 2 or above) would help**, but I don't think WinSCP supports this.
- **Resume/Retry** support/questions: I had it in my settings that it should re-try. And it didn't. The dialog popped up about what I want with a partially complete file. This behaviour is legit, but when we talk about thousands of files, I have no time to sit around the computer all day to see which transfer fails. It shold just retry.

Is there such an SFTP client?

Comment: do you need the encryption and secure connection offered by SFTP? if not, just use FTP :)

Comment: @Gotschi: SFTP is not just security, it also handles special characters better. (Did, for me.) I know this would require like two SSH clients working or more, I don't really care about that part. Server load is not an interest either, it's just the latency that makes it slow, not the server's CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) maybe?
It has threaded transfers and you can tell it to auto-resume/auto-retry.
It's free and open source.

Comment: And you are right, wow. Last time I tried FileZilla for SFTP, it strictly used only ONE thread, no matter what I set. It's awesome. Finally three files at the same time. Technology. **Heck, I used this client so many times I would donate. But they opted-in for that shady SourceForge installer. If they opt-out, I'll send btc/cash donation.**